# How make a webpage into a element only accessible with key?

Tags: javascript, html, key

I have a a button (in a simple index.html written with CSS, HTML, JQuery, and has ajax) that links to a PHP and python file. When you click it, it does stuff.

I would like to make this button accessible to anyone  who I give permission to implement the button on their websites (not my other files, just the literal button) too. I want it to be called with one line of code, and then also pass a "key" (something I provide them), so I can control who can access the button.

I have no clue how to do this. I thought of just creating a super div to hold everything in index.html (but that doesn't solve my key problem, and is probably very inefficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can have a wide array of answers that probably range from basic solutions to a potential user management system.
Here's how I would do this.

1.Tokens!

2.Require that all user requests to the page having the button, come with an additional parameter, a password supplied by you.Upon receipt, I would then check the parameter against a value in my database/file.This is ofcourse may very well not be secure.

3.Check the `HTTP_REFERRER` field.However, as per my understanding, this can be compromised.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132501/how-do-i-provide-more-security-for-checking-source-of-the-request)

**Also read -->**  [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication?rq=1)